# What cleaner fish should I include with my aquarium?

Tags: fish, freshwater, community-aquarium

I am planning on getting a 20 gallon Marina fish tank (24 inches x 12.5 inches x 16.5 inches). I have already planned on getting several species of fish for my aquarium. I am most likely getting two Apistogramma cacatuoides, and 3 guppies. This will be a planted tank, most likely with Dwarf Hairgrass, Amazon Swords, and Rotala rotundifolia. There will also be some decorations that provide optimal hiding places for the Apistogramma. The one thing that I am missing is a cleaner fish. I have heard that the Apistogramma will eat shrimp, and love to claim the territory at the bottom. Are there any cleaning fish that will work with my setup?